# Question about DataGridView event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm currently using DataGridView with combobox as its cell in windows form, and I want whenever I select any new item in that combobox, I'll get a message that I've selected new item. Could anyone please tell which event handler should I need to bind to DataGridView to ensure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

you can use DataGridView EditingControlShowing Event

here you need to check the Control Type of DataGridView Cell

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl))
    {
        ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)e.Control;
        cmb.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cmb_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }
}
```

and in the SelectedIndexChanged of the Combobox

```
    void cmb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        ComboBox cmbSender = (ComboBox)sender;
        MessageBox.Show(cmbSender.Text.ToString());
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, you want to display a message whenever the user selects a new item in the combobox?

If so, this has nothing to do with the gridview, you can use javascript/jQuery to do this. Like so:

```
    $("#GridView1 select").change(function() {
    var x = $(this, 'option:selected').attr('value');
    alert(x);
});
```

I also suggest that you look into creating your own gridviews, they are great for quickly displaying information for testing purposes, but are unpractical to extend. You can create your gridview in code behind with a StringBuilder. I'm using LINQ to SQL in this example but it shows how to do it. Instead of using resultSpan.InnherHtml +=, I suggest using a string builder.

```
public void displayLinqCategory()
{
    StoreDataContext dbm = new StoreDataContext();

    var query = dbm.Categories.Select(c=> new
    {
        Category = c,
        subCategories = dbm.SubCategories.Where(s=> s.CategoryID == c.CategoryID)  
    }).OrderBy(c=> c.Category.Name);


    resultSpan.InnerHtml += "<table class='tableStripe'>";
    resultSpan.InnerHtml += "<tr><th width='1%' colspan='2' style='text-align:left;'>ACTIVE</th><th style='text-align:left;'>NAME</th><th width='1%'>#Items</th></tr>";
    foreach (var result in query)
    {
        int i = result.Category.CategoryID;
        string active = string.Empty;
        bool s = result.Category.Active;

        if (s == true)
            active = "checked='checked'";
        else
            active = "";


        string catBox = string.Format("<input class='categoryChk'value='{0}' type='checkbox' {1} />", i,active);


        resultSpan.InnerHtml += "<tr><td>" + catBox + "</td><td colspan='2'><b>" + result.Category.Name + "</b></td><td></td></tr>";
        foreach (var sub in result.subCategories)
        {
            int si= sub.SubCategoryID;
            string sActive = string.Empty;
            bool subActive = sub.Active;
            if(subActive == true)
                sActive = "checked='checked'";
            else
                sActive ="";

            string subBox = string.Format("<input class='subCatChk' value='{0}' type='checkbox' {1} />", si, sActive);
            resultSpan.InnerHtml += "<tr><td style='background:#FFF;'></td><td>"+subBox+"</td><td>" + sub.SubCategoryName + "</td><td></td></tr>";
        }
    }
    resultSpan.InnerHtml += "</table>";          
}
```

and the result:
[image]

Comment: That was a winforms question... But the grid looks great.